# Backbone listen to event from Raphael freeTransform

Tags: backbone.js, raphael, backbone-events

I know how to handle general events, like click etc., but I am having a problem to understand how to listen to events fired by the function in my render function:

```
function( ft, events) {
   console.log(events);
}); /*fires ["drag start"]
    ["drag"]
    ["apply"] 
    ["drag"] 
    ["apply"]
    ["drag"] 
    etc.*/
```

Now I would like to have handlers in my view that listen to these events. How would I do this?

This is the entire View:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    initialize: function () {
        self = this;
        this.element = paper.rect();
        this.setElement(this.element.node);
        this.delegateEvents(this.events);

    },
    events: { 
        "click": "showHandles",
            "drag end": "dragEndHandler"
    },

    dragEndHandler: function(e){ 
        console.log('dragEnd'); 

    },      

    showHandles: function(e){ 
      this.ft.showHandles();
    },

    render: function(){ 
        this.element.attr({ 
            'x': this.model.get('x'),
            'y': this.model.get('y'),
            'width': this.model.get('width'),
            'height': this.model.get('height'),
            'fill': this.model.get('fill'),
            'cursor': this.model.get('cursor')
        })
        // Add freeTransform with options and callback
        this.ft = paper.freeTransform(this.element, { 
                'keepRatio': ['axisX', 'axisY'],
                'size': 4,
                //set handle
                'attrs': {'fill': '#436eee', 'stroke': '#fff'}
                }, 
                function( ft, events) {
                    console.log(events);/*fires ["drag start"]
                                                        ["drag"]
                                                        ["apply"] 
                                                        ["drag"] 
                                                        ["apply"]
                                                        ["drag"] 
                                                        etc.*/
                });
        return this; 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeTransform accepts a callback as a third argument, you can set it to a function bound to your view :

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'transformed');
       // ...
    },

    transformed: function (ft, events) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(events);
    },

    render: function (){
        // ...
        this.ft = paper.freeTransform(this.element, options, this.transformed);
        return this;
    }
    // ...
});
```

`view.transformed` will be called with this set to the view thanks to `_.bindAll`

To react to specific events, you will have to check if the *events* array contains the associated value:

```
transformed: function (ft, events) {
    if (_.indexOf(events, "scale end")!==-1) {
        console.log("do something with scale end");
    }
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/BC2X3/ for a demo

Or you could build your own event routing method:

```
transformed: function (ft, events) {
    var i = 0, l = events.length, ev;
    for (; i<l; i++) {
        ev = 'transformed_' + events[i].replace(' ', '_');
        if (this[ev])
            this[ev](ft);
    }
},

transformed_scale_end: function() {
    console.log("do something with scale end");
},
transformed_rotate_end: function() {
    console.log("do something with rotate end");
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/BC2X3/1/ for an updated demo

Comment: This is nice, but leaves me with the same question. How to I catch and handle the events fired (now from transformed) Console.log(events) shows me the same list of events. I specifically need to handle the [drag end] event.?

Comment: Could it be as simple as `transformed: function(ft, events){ if(events=='drag end'){ //do stuff }}`?

Comment: @lunacafu As far as I can tell, there is only one callback available so you will have to filter the events to get what you want; See the update for a sample code

Comment: @lunacafu Hadn't seen your last comment. Yes, but you have to check against an array, not a string

Comment: @lunacafu You're welcome, I'll have to look deeper into Raphael, that looks like fun. I added an alternative to the `transformed` code, that could be useful if you have a lot of events to react to.